# Should I send Keep alive packets when I use a TCP connection?

Tags: networking, tcp, keep-alive

My question is , I have create a TCP connection , and when it stays without transfering any data about 1 hour, It already disconnected from the server, but it do not notify me , that it's disconnected,  Should I send keep alive packets to the server ? or should i send keep alive packets from server to client ? Or should i send to both ?

Comment: The OS should be sending TCP keepalives for you.  It might be set to wait a long time before sending them, though; i seem to remember the recommended interval being like 2 hours.

Comment: @cHao The *default* TCP keepalive interval is 2 hours and by default it is *off.*

Comment: @EJP actually its on by default, note other intermediary stateful networking devices will time out way before 2 hours though, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907537/keep-alive-tcp-ip-connected-sockets-over-the-internet-when-how-and-how-much/5149662#5149662

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you should. A few days ago I created a TCP socket/server application, and I got the same problem. I fixed it by starting to send keep alive packets.

If you send keep alive packets, your problem will disappear.

I've heard some people say that the OS will send keep alive packets for you, I am not very familiar with this, but sending keep alive packets explicitly worked for me

Comment: OS defaults to 2 hours and it is not reccomended to change this as it affects all TCP connections made from that machine, so instead implement your own, the question is now how often, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907537/keep-alive-tcp-ip-connected-sockets-over-the-internet-when-how-and-how-much/5149662#5149662

Answer (score 0):

> it do not notify me that it's disconnected

It can't. There is no means whereby it could do so other than inducing an EOS or a 'connection reset' next time you try an I/O.

> Should I send keepalive packets ...

If you have this problem, yes. In general, probably not.